# How to configure account to be able to create/delete folders and files?

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have a newly created domain account (domainname\user1).

This will be used by SQL server agent job proxy credential to run a SSIS package that creates/deletes files and folders on the same computer as the agent job. So effectively the package will run as though it is the user domainname\user1.

What is the permission that I need to assign to domainname\user1 on the computer? For example: I don't want to assign it to the Local administrator group. Should I add it to the Users group? Or any other group?

Comment: Would you be able to assign it to a windows job to run and give it permission to only run that job?  Might make auditing a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You might find a better answer asking this question on [ServerFault](https://www.serverfault.com) but in general I believe you'd just have to add that domain user to the **Folder Security** tab of the root folder where files will be created and deleted. You'll likely want to give that user **Read**, **Write**, and **Modify** permissions in the **Security** tab. Please see [this article](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/) for more information.